# Databricks Community: cannot access dbfs files

Tags: python, databricks, azure-databricks

I have created a databricks community workspace for myself, created some directories and uploaded files. I can list them using `dbutils.fs.ls`.

[image]

However, I cannot access them using python, it looks like this structure is not accessible for some reason. Am I doing something wrong or is it a limitation?

[image]